# How to force an unknown number of flex-items to have the same width in Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, navbar

I want the elements (flex items) in a navbar to retain the same width though there isn't space, in that case the item have to wrap. Furthermore the item number is variable.  Namely I would get this:

```css
      <style>
         nav {
            display: block;
         }
         .navbar ul {
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -moz-box;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            font-family: "Avenir Next", Avenir, Corbel, "Franklin Gothic",
               "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #486a8e;
         }
         .navbar li {
            flex-basis: 25%;
            flex-grow: 1;
            flex-shrink: 0;

            text-transform: uppercase;
            text-align: center;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            background-color: #12459e;
            outline: 1px solid #fff;
         }
         .navbar li a {
            display: block;
            text-decoration: none;
            line-height: 1.75em;
            padding: 1em;
            color: #fff;
         }
      </style>
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/spaceships">Spaceships</a></li>
            <li><a href="/planets">Planets</a></li>
            <li><a href="/stars">Stars</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
```

but this is for a predermined number of items (4 in the code).  I want make this generic and working for any number of items. I tried this setting `flex-basis:0`:

```css
<style>
         nav {
            display: block;
         }
         .navbar ul {
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -moz-box;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            font-family: "Avenir Next", Avenir, Corbel, "Franklin Gothic",
               "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #486a8e;
         }
         .navbar li {
            flex-basis: 0;
            flex-grow: 1;
            flex-shrink: 0;

            text-transform: uppercase;
            text-align: center;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            background-color: #12459e;
            outline: 1px solid #fff;
         }
         .navbar li a {
            display: block;
            text-decoration: none;
            line-height: 1.75em;
            padding: 1em;
            color: #fff;
         }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/spaceships">Spaceships</a></li>
            <li><a href="/planets">Planets</a></li>
            <li><a href="/stars">Stars</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
```

but doesn't work, when I reduce the viewport there will be an item longer than others (that item with the longest world), instead I want EVERY item  with the same width, and when this isn't possible wrap

Comment: min-width:0 to all the items

Comment: With `min-width:0`  the items will have ever the same dimension, but don't wrap when there isn't enough space to the world. instead I want wrap

Comment: No this is not possible with flexbox or any other layout method. You need to know the number of items in any row before and after wrapping and their widths. You will need JS for this.

Comment: It's doable if you don't have the requirement to wrap

Comment: Setting `min-width:150px` it works, but it's brittle because I don't know in advance the dimension of longest item. With JS ok, i would use it in "extrema ratio"

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend CSS Grid for stuff like this. It's so nice to work with. (online tool: https://grid.layoutit.com/ )

```css
<style>
         nav {
            display: block;
         }
         .navbar ul {
            display: grid; 
            grid-auto-flow: column; 
            grid-auto-columns: 1fr; 
            font-family: "Avenir Next", Avenir, Corbel, "Franklin Gothic",
               "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #486a8e;
         }
         .navbar li {
            text-transform: uppercase;
            text-align: center;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            background-color: #12459e;
            outline: 1px solid #fff;
         }
         .navbar li a {
            display: block;
            text-decoration: none;
            line-height: 1.75em;
            padding: 1em;
            color: #fff;
         }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/spaceships">Spaceships</a></li>
            <li><a href="/planets">Planets</a></li>
            <li><a href="/stars">Stars</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
```

Comment: Your solution don't resolve my question, when I resize down still there will be an item longer than others

Comment: Yep just saw that.

Comment: @Umbert Fixed it for you.

Comment: Thanks, but this new implementation doesn't work in the way I would too.